# randomForest en R: selección variables independientes

Tags: r

Tengo un dataframe con muchas variables y solo quiero usar 3 como independientes para predecir la dependiente.
Esta sentencia usa todo el dataframe -creo-:
train=sample(1:nrow(df),3000)
RF<-randomForest(Dependiente~., data=df, subset = train, na.action = na.roughfix)

Y esta otra utiliza solo una variable del dataframe:
RF<-randomForest(Dependiente~Inpendiente, data=df, subset = train, na.action = na.roughfix)

He probado esto y no funciona:
RF<-randomForest(Dependiente~Independiente_1, Independiente_2, Independiente_3, data=df, subset = train, na.action = na.roughfix))

¿Cómo lo hago? Gracias

Comment: También he probado a crear un nuevo dt solo con las variables que me interesan, pero en ese caso me indica que na.roughfix funciona solo con numéricas o factor. Sigue sin dar resultado aunque aplique la sentencia as.numeric() a las variables en cuestión.

Comment: Prueba definir la formula como  `Dependiente~Independiente_1 + Independiente_2 + Independiente_3`